# Unable to fetch BasicReport.htm_source.xml in Openscript Test Result folder after execution

Tags: openscript

I'm trying to create a custom HTML report out of `BasicReport.htm_source.xml` in the Test Result folder.

I'm not able to access the xml file during script execution. Eventhough I used the XML rendering function in the `finish()` node.

Is their anyway I can use the `BasicReport.htm_source.xml` after script execution?

Comment: We'll need to see a sample of your source XML and the code you're trying to use.

Comment: Function used to convert XML is below

  Source xml = new StreamSource(new File("C:\\Reports\\ERseouce.xml"));
    Source xslt = new StreamSource("C:\\Reports\\ExecutionReport_source.xsl");
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Reports\\ExecutionReport_source.html");
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trasform = tFactory.newTransformer(xslt);
    trasform.transform(xml, new StreamResult(sw));
    fw.write(sw.toString());
    fw.close();

Comment: I have the xml function and xml with xsl in the below question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654598/xslt-is-not-reading-the-xml-using-transformer-factory

Comment: Put code in your question, in a code block, so it's readable, please. Also, copy some of the relevant XML the same way. You want people to be able to look at your question and have all of the information they need.

Answer (score 0):

finish section is still execution, in short no way to do this. 
if an Oracle customer, use official channel to create ER